# Expression - returns those elements in the factor ‘equal to’ special vector

Tags: factors

I would like to have the output _ survival plot for each stage. In particular ‘iii’ which the rhizoid life stage, i have tried but can only get if I seperate in excel. Time consuming now I have all data for three treatments.

I know I have to recreate another list from stage - this is what i'm wasting time on.
I basically then want to get the nutrient treatment (PES) and confirm stages - what treatment (light intensity) with PES on which day was first and with what survival proportion?

Image attached-is what i've been using for individual stages but  giving me different plots all the time. I have now gone back to original data set before I extract information stage by stage.

`enter code here` Datase <- summarySE(DataAll,na.rm=TRUE, measurevar='Survival', groupvars=c("Location","Stage","time"))
Datase$Location<-factor(Datase$Location, labels=c("P0","P5","P10","P15","P20","PR"))
Datase$Stage<-factor(Datase$Stage, labels=c("i","ii","iii","iv","v","vi"))
Datase$time<-factor(Datase$time, labels=c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","10","14"))

P0 = ggplot(Datase[Datase$Location=="P0",], aes(colour= factor(Stage), x=time, y=Survival,group=(Stage),shape = factor(Stage))) +
theme_bw()+xlab("Time")+ylab(expression(paste("Stage Prop", " ", sep="")))+theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())+
geom_line(position=position_dodge(0),size = 0.5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=14))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")+ theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank()) +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=Survival-se,ymax=Survival+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
geom_point(position=position_dodge(0),size = 5)+ theme(text = element_text(size=14))+guides(shape = guide_legend(reverse=F))+ theme(legend.position="none",legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "mm"))+facet_grid(.~Location, scales="free_y")  +geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(0),aes(ymin=Survival-se,ymax=Survival+se),width=.1,colour="black") +
facet_wrap(~Location) + ggtitle("PES - 0 umol") +
coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,100)) +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))